# Add unpublished but widely cited paper to CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I wrote an expository term paper in graduate school and posted it on my website, never trying to get it into a journal. Google Scholar says it now has 19 citations from various countries ("widely" is of course relative; what I mean is that this is more citations than my other publications have).

Since the article apparently resonated with an audience, should it now appear on my CV? If so, should I describe it with the name of the professor or course for which I wrote it, or just a title with no venue?

Comment: The question seems impossible to answer without more information about your current career stage, number and quality of research publications, and the quality and topic of the expository paper. One can imagine scenarios where the expository paper does make you look a bit more impressive, and others where it just makes you seem desperate to pad your CV with unimportant things. Not sure what more can be said.

Comment: 19 citations doesn't yet quite count as "widely cited". But at a certain stage of a career, it might provide a noticeable boost to a CV, and then it's of course useful to list it.

Comment: What field are you in?  In my little corner of mathematics, 19 citations would be pretty sweet.

Comment: Is it a good paper - one you would be proud of?

Comment: Is it possible this paper could be published in a review-type journal? Maybe you should submit it. There are several such journals that do "wrap up" or "state-of-the-art" type articles. The things "everybody knows" but *not* everybody knows, or knows in detail.

Comment: Why not? As long as you're happy to defend it if someone brings it up in an interview.

Answer (score 17):

One strategy is to do a deep-dive to check up on the **quality** of those 19 citations.

- If you end up impressed: submit your paper to a journal. (The peer review will add some quality or quality control; the paper is less likely to disappear; and the author gets recognition.)
- If not: maybe just leave it as is and don't include on CV.

(I had a similar experience as you describe. Sometimes some less-serious researchers just want to cite something with the right words in the title... not saying that's the case with your citations but it's worth checking.)

Comment: Scientific journals typically focus on publishing *new results*. If the paper does not present new results, but rather *old results explained nicely*, that is, if it's mostly teaching material rather than research material, getting it published at a journal may be difficult.

Comment: @Uwe - many fields have teaching-specific journals where such a paper might fit well.

Comment: @Uwe, Jon is correct.  There are also journals that only publish reviews.  And mercenary editors who will publish anything that gets many citations.

Comment: @Uwe that depends on the field. In my particular field we have a concept called a "pearl" which is exactly something that might not be quite novel but is explained in a "beautiful" way. Pearls are often quite different beasts from the regular research papers but are nonetheless valued.

Comment: I guess it's time for the Academia.SE mantra: "Academia varies more than you think it does."

Comment: In my field, some journals in addition to review papers also publish tutorial papers. An email to the editor beforehand may help - and if they don't publish such papers they may be able to tell other journals in your field who do.

Answer (score 12):

I think its becoming more common to have divide the "publications" section of a CV into "Peer-reviewed primary research" and "Reviews, pre-prints and other non-reviewed publications". Would that work for you?

Answer (score 9):

> Add unpublished but widely cited paper to CV?

**If it's widely cited, then it has been published.** Perhaps you mean - published only in non-refereed venues? If such work is meaningful and you feel like showcasing it, then you can certainly put it in your CV. I've done this with a monograph of mine that's on ArXiv - and it's not even widely cited.

Comment: And if it is already being cited and genuinely being interacted with by other researchers then you could think of it as going through the real peer-review process now - that's something many papers in peer-reviewed journals don't actually get!

Comment: This. It is very normal to have publications that are not peer reviewed in the CV: posters, oral presentations, technical reports, proceedings papers (in my field they are not peer-reviewed and thus rare), I also list some software there.

Comment: To add to this, ArXiv has *some* quality control. Its not peer review, but if it gets in, its at least, not some random work, but something worth reviewing in general. So yes, if its in ArXiv, its OK to list it in your CV, I think.

Answer (score 8):

> Since the article apparently resonated with an audience, should it now appear on my CV? If so, should I describe it with the name of the professor or course for which I wrote it, or just a title with no venue?

**Whether it should be included depends on your career path.**

For research positions, you should definitely include the manuscript on your CV and I'd suggest treating it like a technical report. (You could mention the course for which it was written (and possibly even the professor), but that depends how you introduce the work.) For other positions, it depends how relevant you consider the achievement.